# Set of natural numbers as the intersection of inductive sets

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, quantifiers, natural-numbers

I was studying foundations of arithmetic, and reasoning about the set of natural numbers. In Peano arithmetic, we can talk about $\mathbb{N}$ without defining it explicitly or trying to prove its existence (or simply not talk about $\mathbb{N}$ at all), since that is not the purpose of the system.

But I was thinking about a way to define $\mathbb{N}$. Some sources try to do that by postulating some axiom asserting the existence of an inductive set, and extracting the naturals from it in a weird way (perhaps weird because the notation seemed strange to me).

My reasoning, however, is as follows:

We first define a set $I$ as the set of all sets $S$ that satisfy the conditions $0\in S$ and $\forall n[(n\in S)\rightarrow(n^{+}\in S)]$:

$$[S\in I]\Leftrightarrow[(0\in S)\land\forall n[(n\in S)\rightarrow (n^{+}\in S)]]$$

Finally, we define $\mathbb{N}$ as the intersection of all the sets in $I$:

$$\mathbb{N}:=\bigcap_{S\in I}(S)$$

My question is whether this definition is correct or not, and whether it is circular somehow, specially in the condition with quantification over $n$:

**Are we already assuming the universe of discourse as $\mathbb{N}$ in the quantified condition?**

Some insights I had so far:

1. It appears that the condition could be replaced with $\forall n\in S(n^+\in S)$, but I'm not sure if this is different though.
2. Correct me if I'm wrong: in standard set-theory, we assume the universe of discourse to be all sets, so I think that the universe is not necessarily a set, otherwise we could reach a paradox. So maybe the universe of discourse of the quantified condition is not necessarily $\mathbb N$. I wonder if we can talk about the natural numbers collectively without referring to the set that we are trying to define, or if we need a larger superset containing them, but not only them, for the definition to hold.

Comment: Set theory assume that the "universe" of sets has at least one infinite set and then define a "proxy" for the intuitive collection of *natural* numbers. Our intuition about the counting numbers is prior to the formal theory of arithmetic, as well as our intuition about collections and concepts is prior to our formal theory of sets and classes.

Comment: A way of rephrasing mihaild’s answer is that your definition is fine provided we remove the assertion that $I$ is a set and understand why the intersection of a nonempty class of sets is a set (which is basically just the $I_A$ trick). Also would be good to mention somewhere that the axiom of infinity is what tells us $I$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\forall n \in S(n^+ \in S)$ and $\forall n ((n \in S) \rightarrow (n^+ \in S))$ are equivalent (and usually the first is just short way to write the second).

Property you use ($0 \in S \wedge \forall n \in S(n^+ \in S)$) is called "inductive" (we say "$S$ is inductive set"). But your $I$ is ill-defined: there is no set of all inductive sets (there are too many inductive sets).

However, in set theory there is axiom of infinity, that says there is at least one inductive set. Let $A$ be some inductive set, and let $I_A$ be family of all inductive subsets of $A$ (including $A$ itself). Then we can define $\mathbb N$ as $\bigcap\limits_{S \in I_A} S$. We need to prove that this intersection doesn't depend on choice of $A$, but it's easy.

"Universe" in such context is usually considered to be all sets, and we need to find $\mathbb N$ among all sets. Peano arithmetic doesn't speak about $\mathbb N$ directly, but when we speak about models of arithmetic, we need $\mathbb N$ as a set we can define functions and subsets on.

Comment: If $I$ is ill-defined because there might be too many inductive sets, the problem could arise with $I_A$ as well, right? Perhaps that's why you chose to define $I_A$ as a family instead. If that's the case, what if we define $I$ as a family as well? It appears that we avoid having to prove something about the choice of $A$ being arbitrary or not (with respect to the intersection and it's dependency on our choice of $A$).

Comment: This problem can't arise with $I_A$, because we have axiom of subsets (there is a set of all subsets of $A$), and axiom of specification (for any set $X$ and property, there is set of all elements **in X** satisfying this property - the bolded part is very important), together they give existence of set of all inductive subsets of $A$. The problem with defining $I$ as family of sets is that working with proper classes is often more complicated and unnecessary both in general and in this case.